# Problem executing shortcuts from Gnome menu

Tags: 16.04, gnome, menu, shortcuts

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome Flashback desktop. When I drag icons out of Gnome menu to create shortcuts on the desktop, the shortcuts are not executable. They appear on the desktop as *.desktop files. I have to right click, go into Properties, Permissions and check "Allow executing files as a program". I've tried going to Usr, Share, Applications and setting the entire contents to "Allow executing files as a program", but that didn't work. Any ideas on how to fix it so they're automatically executable?